# mysql date ranges with larger date before smaller date

Tags: mysql, database, date

I want to store date ranges to allow for hours of operation to be conditional upon a date range to accommodate for seasonal changes. i was using the following condition

```
date_start < CURDATE() AND date_end > CURDATE()
```

The problem with this is if the start date is larger(September) than the end date (June)

In my database, I am storing the dates(2017-07-01) as a date but the year is irrelevant(I do not even give the user a chance to select a year in input). I am just storing it as a date for validation purposes (if there is a better way I'm up for it). In the example above the range is between September of the prior year to June of the current year. How can I accommodate this WITHOUT relying on the year. Keep in mind that a date range could simply be January to February of the same year so, I need the flexibility.

I guess i could convert the dates to a mathematical number and see if the values are greater than or equal but this seems like quite a bit of overhead.

What would be an effective way I could query the database to determine that the current date is between the correct start and end dates?

Comment: Use a case statement

Comment: the condition is on a join statement

Answer (score 0):

```
(date_start < date_end AND date_start < CURDATE() AND date_end > CURDATE()) OR (date_start > date_end AND (date_start > CURDATE() OR CURDATE() < date_end))
```

may be this helps

Comment: The problem would be the years  if i stored the dates as 0000-06-17 or 2017-06-17 and a generate a year from curdate() if would eventually wouldnt work correctly as the year fom curdate() would always become larger

Comment: I like the start of it though. i didnt even consider testing which of my stored dates is larger and then adjusting the conditions based on it.

Comment: You can make yearfixed - for example 2017. Store 2017 in database and do not use CURDATE() - instead use "current date" based on 2017.  Or, maybe, you can change way of storing date range - store month and days only.

Answer (score 0):

Aha!

Using your idea of testing for which date is actually before one another we rendered the following condition

```
( date_start < date_end AND date_start < CURDATE() AND date_end > CURDATE() ) OR ( date_start > date_end AND (date_start > CURDATE() AND CURDATE() < date_end) )
```

However, this takes the year into account which is not desired

I then figured that if we formatted each curdate to effectively remove the year such as

```
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '0000-%m-%d')
```

i would then replace each curdate with the above (assuming i am storing the dates in my database as 0000-mm-dd). I did not like this because i am recalculating the same number again and again. I thought maybe i could store an alias with the amount but on a join statement i cannot do this. Therefore my solution is a combination of php and mysql placeholder.

i user php to find out the current date once and use it in a place holder

```
$data = date('0000-m-d', time );
```

i adjust the conditions in the original statement to
    ( date_start < date_end AND date_start < :c AND date_end > :c ) OR ( date_start > date_end AND (date_start > :c AND :c < date_end) )

and add the variable $date to my sql array and bingo!